# "Undefined" error using Behave with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-behave

i'm writing a Behave feature file and facing uncertain "Undefined" error just before step with context table. should mention that i've made two features before without any problem but on english. This exact feature with "Undefined" error is on Russian, maybe this is the problem?
I'm using Behave 1.2.6, python 3.8.0 and PyCharm Professional.

Step with error:

```
    И Выбраны производители:
      | name |
      | JVC  |
      | Sony |
```

breakpoint on this step's function doesn't invoke so i'm assuming the error is with reading the step itself

step method code:

```
@step("Выбраны производители:")
def select_brand(context):
    for row in context.table:
        ...
```

Comment: Have you tried just changing the Russian text of the step to English (or something ascii) to see if it makes a difference? That would verify whether the encoding is the problem

Comment: perhaps try with unicode mark ie: `@step(u"Выбраны производители:")` ?